# How do I get elements of array by their indexes?

Tags: ruby

Is there any short possible way to have this executed:

```
var1 = %w{sub1 sub2 sub3 sub4 sub5}
var2 = [1,4]
```

I need to return the 1,4 values of var2 from var1. Now my output should be *`["sub2", "sub5"]`*

Comment: Your examples are irrelevant for the question. Also the title.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this place. I will correct myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var1 = %w{sub1 sub2 sub3 sub4 sub5}
var2 = [1,4]

var1.values_at(*var2) # => ["sub2", "sub5"]
```